# nest() followed by map() for linear models

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

My data looks like this:

```
#>   group.name x y
#> 1          a 1 2
#> 2          a 2 4
#> 3          a 3 6
#> 4          b 1 4
#> 5          b 2 3
#> 6          b 3 2
#> 7          c 1 2
#> 8          c 2 5
#> 9          c 3 8
```

```r
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
   group.name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
            x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
            y = c(2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 8)
)
```

I'm trying to run a linear model for each 'group.name' so I tried the code below to:

1. `group_by` the group.name
2. create a nested df
3. `map()` the `lm` function to the nested df.

But I'm getting an error. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse) 
models <- df %>%
  group_by(group.name) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  map(~ lm(y ~ x, data = .))


#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
models
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'models' not found
```

Answer (score 4):

A very similiar solution that I find a bit more intuitive is to keep the models in a data frame until you want to extract them.

```
models_df <- df %>%
  nest(-group.name) %>% 
  mutate(models = map(data, ~lm(y ~ x, data = .)))
```

which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group.name data             models
  <chr>      <list>           <list>
1 a          <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>  
2 b          <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>  
3 c          <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>
```

Then if you want to extract the model you do:

```
models_df %>% 
  pull(models)
```

which gives you the list of models:

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          0            2  

[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          5           -1  

[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
         -1            3
```

Answer (score 4):

Problems like this are why the [tidyverse package `broom`](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom) exists.

```
require(broom)
df %>% 
    group_by(group.name) %>%
    do(tidy(lm(data = ., formula = y ~ x)))

df %>% 
    group_by(group.name) %>%
    do(glance(lm(data = ., formula = y ~ x)))
```

The first code block puts out a *data frame* of best-fit parameters.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   group.name [3]
  group.name term        estimate std.error  statistic    p.value
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 a          (Intercept)       0   0.        NaN       NaN       
2 a          x                 2   0.        Inf         0.      
3 b          (Intercept)       5.  1.02e-15    4.91e15   1.30e-16
4 b          x                -1.  4.71e-16   -2.12e15   3.00e-16
5 c          (Intercept)      -1.  1.36e-15   -7.37e14   8.64e-16
6 c          x                 3.  6.28e-16    4.78e15   1.33e-16
```

The second code block puts out a *data frame* of summary statistics from the fitting operation.

The key is that the results of all of the fits are formatted in a convenient data frame structure.  Not in lists, named lists, or S3 or S4 objects with arbitrary structures.  Downstream manipulation of modeling results can use the familiar tidyverse tools you already know, once the models are in dataframe format.  If you're doing lots of this type of thing, you may want to give broom a look. (Disadvantages would be introduction of another dependency, and if you've already got a lot of code written to parse the structures of lists of model fits, you'll need to re-tweak those.)

Answer (score 2):

The data given to `map` is not in the format expected. Try using `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(group.name,keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(~lm(y ~ x, data = .))


#[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#          0            2  


#[[2]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#          5           -1  


#[[3]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#         -1            3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
df %>% group_by(group.name) %>% summarise(mod=list(lm(y~x))) ->df1
df1$mod[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#          0            2
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, and especially in this simple case, incorporating the grouping variable within your model is going to be much much simpler.

```
md <- lm(y ~ x*group.name - 1, data = df) 
summary(md)
```

Adding the `-1` removes the intercept, which will then be given by the variable `group.namea`, `group.nameb` and so on. The summary

```
lm(formula = y ~ x * group.name - 1, data = df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9 
 1.052e-15 -2.104e-15  1.052e-15  4.019e-16 -8.038e-16  4.019e-16 -2.313e-17  4.626e-17 -2.313e-17 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
x              2.000e+00  1.126e-15  1.776e+15   <2e-16 ***
group.namea   -1.820e-15  2.433e-15 -7.480e-01    0.509    
group.nameb    5.000e+00  2.433e-15  2.055e+15   <2e-16 ***
group.namec   -1.000e+00  2.433e-15 -4.110e+14   <2e-16 ***
x:group.nameb -3.000e+00  1.593e-15 -1.883e+15   <2e-16 ***
x:group.namec  1.000e+00  1.593e-15  6.278e+14   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.593e-15 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.169e+31 on 6 and 3 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

gives all 3 models. We have

- Model for group a: `y = -1.82*10^-15 + 2 * x`
- Model for group b: `y = 10 + (2 - 3) * x = 10 - 1 x`
- Model for group c: `y = -1 + (2 + 1) *x = -1 + 3 * x`

Comment: This approach assumes that the distribution of residuals is not a function of the grouping variable.  The approaches where seperate fits are done for each group do not make that assumption.  Sometimes you want one, sometimes the other, but they are different.

Comment: Under the assumption that the residual distribution is a function of the grouping variables, one would (and likely should) move to linear mixed effect models. While true that the assumption is affected, one leaves out the effect of the grouping variable in model tests if the grouping variable is not including. Not to say, that one could always use standard methods (qqplot of residuals for example) to test whether any model assumption is in fact broken.